# Default casing pattern in JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#

What is the default casing pattern in JsonSerializerSettings? Is it Pascal casing? If not, how to use the Pascal casing pattern when creating a new custom JsonSerializerSettings class?

I've tried to use the default resolver in the JsonSerializerSettings.

Answer (score 0):

You really should tell us what you have tried but isn't working so we can help you better.

Anyway, the [default is `PascalCase`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultNamingStrategy.htm) (you can change it to `camelCase` or `snake_case`), and [here's a working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcPGVW).

```
public record Animal(int NumOfLegs);

var pet = new Animal(3);

// DefaultNamingStrategy() below will give you Pascal Case.
// Also see: CamelCaseNamingStrategy() and SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pet, new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { 
        NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy()
    }
});
```